# rasa nlu fallback is returning intent instead of question

Tags: python, rasa, rasa-x

I am using rasa (version 2) and with [this configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66558761/fall-back-policy-is-not-working-with-rasa-framework) I have integrated the `FallbackClassifier`.

But this returns the intent name instead of any question with yes and no button. And if i press yes, then it asks the question to user

```
Did you mean intent_name
```

this is how conversation went

[image]

Instead of showing intent_name it should show the question. Am i missing something?

And on console

```
ERROR    rasa_sdk.endpoint  - No registered action found for 
name 'action_default_fallback'.
```

Comment: hi,

while the chatbot is giving the correct answers and responses for the small data set where my nlu file has around 900 lines

Comment: can you help me out ,i have a large data set which is round 12689 and i have trained it successfully but for every intent example i am getting the response blank which is considered as the nlu_fallback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the fallback policy, rasa shows the option for most likely intent.

And by default, Rasa shows raw intent name for fallback, as we have not provided any mapping configuration. So if it finds the intent `make_reserverations`, it will show

```
Did you mean make_reserverations?
```

and offer two buttons Yes and No.

To show custom or user friendly phrase, need to implement the action `action_default_ask_affirmation`

You have to create a class in **actions.py**

```
class ActionDefaultAskAffirmation(Action):
    """Asks for an affirmation of the intent if NLU threshold is not met."""

    def name(self):
        return "action_default_ask_affirmation"

    def __init__(self):
        self.intent_mappings = {}
        # read the mapping of 'intent and valid question' from a csv and store it in a dictionary
        with open(
            INTENT_DESCRIPTION_MAPPING_PATH, newline="", encoding="utf-8"
        ) as file:
            csv_reader = csv.reader(file)
            for row in csv_reader:
                self.intent_mappings[row[0]] = row[1]

    def run(self, dispatcher, tracker, domain):
        # from the list of intents get the second higher predicted intent
        # first will be nlu_fallback  
        predicted_intent_info = tracker.latest_message["intent_ranking"][1]
        # get the most likely intent name
        intent_name = predicted_intent_info["name"]
        # get the prompt for the intent
        intent_prompt = self.intent_mappings[intent_name]

        # Create the affirmation message and add two buttons to it.
        # Use '/<intent_name>' as payload to directly trigger '<intent_name>'
        # when the button is clicked.
        message = "Did you mean '{}'?".format(intent_prompt)

        buttons = [
            {"title": "Yes", "payload": "/{}".format(intent_name)},
            {"title": "No", "payload": "/out_of_scope"},
        ]

        dispatcher.utter_message(message, buttons=buttons)

        return []
```

and then need mapping csv file like this

```
//intent_name,User_Friendly_Phrase
bot_challenge,I am bot
```

and then make an entry in **domain.yml** under `actions`

Answer (score 0):

The `TwoStageFallback` actually seems successful. I think the issue is that while you succesfully affirm the intent `mood_great`, your assistant doesn't know which action to run next and hence triggers `action_core_fallback` (configured in the `RulePolicy` configuration) (see more in the docs [here](https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/fallback-handoff#handling-low-action-confidence)).

Did you add `action_default_fallback` to your domain file? In case you did: You need to define an approppriate [custom action](https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/custom-actions) in that case. If you don't want to override the default implementation you can remove the `action_default_fallback` from your domain file.